# Pass data to ngDialog in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

How can I pass data to ngDialog in Angular? Most examples are using scope to do this. But I don't use scope in my controller. What should I do? Here is my code inside my controller:

```
var vm = this;
AuthService.login(user.name,user.password).then(function() {
      $state.go('dashboard');
    },function(error) {
      vm.user.password = '';
      ngDialog.open({
        template: '<h2>Error</h2><p>{{error}}</p>',
        plain: true
      });
    })
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do it using `resolve` the same way you do with routers. Whatever properties you define in `resolve` can then be injected into the controller

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: '<h2>Error</h2><p>{{error}}</p>',
    plain: true,
    resolve:{
       error: function(){
            return error;
        }
    },
    controller: function($scope,error){
        $scope.error = error;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Don't quite understand. {{error}} still not showing the correct data.It's still empty. Sorry, I'm still new to angular.

Comment: OK..I was using pseudo objects ...updated code so error should be displayed now

Comment: It works. The controller use **error** function in resolve to return the passed parameter **error**. Thank you.

Comment: It is not required to use 'resolve' option, You could simply assign the argument 'error' to the property '$scope.error' in the controller of ngDialog.